# Move large member object out of class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, memory

#### Background/Example:

I currently have a class like the following:

```
class Element {
  Large l1;
  OtherLarge l2;
  Small s1;
  VerySmall s2;
};
```

where `Large` and `OtherLarge` are relatively big (~80 bytes) whereas `Small` and `VerySmall` are fairly small (~4 to 16 Byte).

On these elements, I operate in two ways:

- sorting them in various ways. During this, only members `s1` and `s2` are accessed/needed.
- combining the large members in various way (e.g. matrix-matrix multiplication).

The second class of operations is already fairly fast and can be parallelised easily, hence I’d like to speed up the first class of operations more. Comparing with another class `Element2` where I replaced the two big data members by 8-byte integers doing nothing tells me that if I can somehow replace the direct data members `l1` and `l2` by pointers of one sort or another to dynamically-allocated elements elsewhere, I’ll already get a big win.

For reference, all member types have both copy and move constructors and can be both copied and moved, but moving them is much much cheaper. `Large` and `OtherLarge` also allocate a lot of memory by themselves, so allocating a bit more isn’t necessarily horrible.

#### Concrete question

Is it possible, and if so, what is the best way, to replace a direct member object of a class with a pointer to a dynamically-allocated object elsewhere; preserving the behaviour of a direct member as closely as possible w.r.t construction, destruction, member variable access etc? If I use a `std::unique_ptr<Large>` naively, I assume I’ll have to dereference it half the time/take care of copying specially? Ideally I’d like the new member object to behave just as if the old, big member object was still there.

Comment: So basically, you want to reduce the size of `Element`?

Comment: If I were you I would test it out. You may be surprised by the results. Cache locality can cause huge impact on performance and 160 bytes is not quite large. If number of elements is not a high number, you may use a different sorting algorithm which would reduce element moves instead of comparisons.

Comment: Have you thought about using a shared_ptr instead?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I’d like to reduce the size of the element itself. @CemKalyoncu Unfortunately it does have quite an effect, if I replace the large elements by integers (and still don't use them), things go much faster as I can fit up to 4 `Element`s into a single cacheline (rather than using two per element). I’m not quite sure why a shared_ptr would help, as far as I can see, reference counting is not needed.

Comment: Regarding a different choice of algorithm: Each individual call to the sorting only works on 20 to 50 elements, but that has to happen fairly often in a serial region of the code. The small size means that some sort of set-up work first (where I walk over the elements and pick out the needed data members) or a more intelligent algorithm using O(log(n)n) rather than the current O(n²) doesn’t help much. Obviously I’d like to avoid reworking everything, hence the minimal-impact question.

Answer (score 4):

unique_ptr will not solve your issue as sorting may involve copying (for swapping). I am fairly certain that flyweight pattern can solve your issues. Here is a simple implementation:

```
class Element_data {
public:
    large l1,l2;
};

std::vector<Element_data> data;

class Element {
public:
   small s1, s2;
   int data_ind;

   large &GetLarge1() { 
       assert(data_ind>=0 && data_ind<data.size);
       return data[data_ind].l1; 
   }
};

std::vector<Element> elements;
...
std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), &mysortfn);
```

Why not use pointers? They may get invalidated if you add new members to the data vector. Also this approach allows you to keep your data together so it might get loaded into cache easier.

Additional points:

- If you are deleting an element for good, you should erase the data as well.
- Adding new member is quite simple
- While sorting or some other operations, it is safe to have more than one Element to point to the same data

Edit: Just to make sure you won't run into problems if it is not clear, destructor of Element should not destroy data. You can provide custom deleter for this. The best approach would be to develop a container that can do this, erase the element and data with erase function.

Comment: Did you mean `std::vector<Element_data> data`?

Comment: @MariusBancila exactly, fixed.

Comment: Hm, yes. Rebuilding it as a struct-of-arrays rather than an array-of-structs would probably be the fastest but also make the code in some places much more ugly. Keeping an index into the other arrays in the structs of the main array seems to be a nice middle ground. I’ll think about it some more and wait a day or so for possibly more answers, but overall I fear this is as close as I can get. Thank you!